# Dealing properly with closed connection with pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.7, pymysql

I am making a class to unify the way we deal with the database and I want to make sure the connection is closed when the object is not used anymore, the class is something like this:

```
import pymysql

class MyContainerdbclass:

    def __init__():
     self.connection = pymysql.connect(.....)
    
    def foo():
        ...

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

It works pretty fine but when the program finished I got an annoying warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../mysql.py", line 12, in __del__
  File "...../python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 359, in close
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I just added a try/except to avoid this but I am not very sure if this is safe.

```
def __del__(self):
    try:
        self.connection.close()
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

As far as I could research, there are no open connections left when this object is destroyed. Let me know if you agree with this approach.

Comment: You don't want to do this. The connection should always be a local variable in each method that uses one, allocated on entry, and closed via all possible exit paths. Ditto statements and result sets. Otherwise you run into liveness, thread-safety, and many other problems.

Comment: Well the main problem when I faced this was there were open connections spread in different scripts. This class is being used as a single object in the rest of the code, so no matter which script call this object, with this method I am making sure the connection is closed at the end of the program.

Comment: But now you have to make sure the object is destroyed. There is no advantage, and all the disadvantages I mentioned, and more.

Comment: Not really, that's the point of using `__del__`, garbage collector will make sure of that.

Comment: You don't want to rely on garbage collection to close connections. You want to do it yourself, manually, as soon as possible. to avoid overloading teh server. And surely the connection will close itself anyway when garbage-collected?

Comment: Why would not you trust in the garbage collector? It most reliable than the actual programmer if I expect them to close the connection manually.

Comment: Because (1) it takes too long to happen, and (2) if you are going to trust it you dont' need the code you posted, because the `Connection` will get collected itself if it leaks. I've already said this.

Comment: I did not know `Connection` closed the connection by it self. As you said, it would not be necessary the code. Thanks!